# VBA How to create script to move a worksheet from a lot of xls files to specific workbook in xlsx format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of xls files (around 40 files) in

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\archivos\
```

Each file has a only worksheet. I have to open each one xls file to copy the worksheet.

"Right click on the worksheet tab and select move option, select the master file to located in"

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\MASTER.xlsx
```

This Master file is a xlsx file (word,2007-2010) which must contain the 40 worksheet in a specific order.

I want to copy the whole sheet per file, not by ranges A1...A200

I found this code that use ranges and that its relation is to copy a file to many files, it is not what I look for but is resembles it.

```
    Sub Prueba()
Dim file As String
   Dim myPath As String
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim rng As Range

   Dim wbMaster As Workbook
   'if master workbook already opened
   'Set wbMaster = Workbooks("MASTER.xlsx")
   'if master workbook is not opened
   Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\archivos\MAQUINA DE MOTOR MONTO.xls")

   Set rng = wbMaster.Sheets("MAQUINA DE MOTOR MONTO").Range("A1:R300")

   myPath = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\" ' note there is a back slash in the end
   file = Dir(myPath & "*.xls*")
   While (file <> "")

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & file)
        rng.Copy
        With wb.Worksheets("MAQUINA DE MOTOR MONTO").Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End With

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Set wb = Nothing

        file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

The other codes that I have seen must be executed in the active worksheet

Eg.

```
Sub MoveSheet_SpecificWorkbook ()
Sheets("Sheet1").Move Before:=Workbooks("YourWorkbookName.xls").Sheets(“Sheet3”)
End Sub
```

This script must be isolated from the archivos folder and his files and the Master File too. As an executable file (double click to run)

I want to this script must be located in `C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\`.

Comment: Are you asking for people to write code for you? That is not what SO is for. If you have a specific question as to how something works or can’t find a bug, please amend your question so it can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetsToMasterExcelFile()

' Change this to wherever the .xls files are located.'
Const XLSFOLDERPATH as string = 
"C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\archivos\"

' Change to wherever you saved the text file (see end of post).'
Const LISTFILEPATH as string = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\archivos\ListOfXLSFiles.txt"

' Read 40-file list into memory '
Dim FileContents as string
Open LISTFILEPATH for binary access read as #1
Filecontents = space$(lof(1))
Get #1, 1, filecontents
Close #1

' Build array of filenames to iterate through. '
Dim XLSFilenames() as string
Xlsfilenames = split(filecontents,vbnewline,-1,vbbinarycompare)

Dim MasterFilePath as string
MasterFilePath = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\Report " & format(date,"d mmmm yyyy") & ".xlsx"

' Set MasterWorkbook'
Dim MasterWorkbook as workbook
On error resume next
Set MasterWorkbook = application.Workbooks(mid$(MasterFilePath,instrrev(masterfilepath,"\",-1,vbbinarycompare)+1))
On error goto 0
If masterworkbook is nothing then

If len(dir(masterfilepath))>0 then set masterworkbook = application.Workbooks.Open(masterfilepath)

End if

If not(masterworkbook is nothing) then

With masterworkbook

Dim XLSworkbook as workbook
Dim Index as long

For index = ubound(xlsfilenames) to lbound(xlsfilenames) step -1 ' iterate through array in reverse.'

If Len(dir(XLSFolderpath & xlsfilenames(index)))>0 and len(xlsfilenames(index))>0 then

Set xlsworkbook = Application.workbooks.open(xlsfolderpath & xlsfilenames(index)) 'Maybe open .xls file as read only (as you neither modify the file nor know whether another user has it open already)'

Xlsworkbook.worksheets(1).copy before:= .worksheets(1)

' Code does not check if there is already a worksheet in the master Excel file with the same name as the worksheet being copied; will throw error if there is as you cannot have two worksheets of the same name in the same workbook. You did not mention that you needed this in your question.'

Xlsworkbook.close false 'Do not save any changes whilst closing the .xls file'

Else
Msgbox("No file was found at: " & xlsfolderpath & xlsfilenames(index))
Exit sub
End if

Next index

' Setting object reference below is just to verify that the hoja1 sheet exists in the masterworkbook before we attempt to delete it.'
Dim SheetToDelete as worksheet

On error resume next
Set SheetToDelete = .worksheets("hoja1")
On error goto 0

If not(sheettodelete is nothing) then
Application.displayalerts = false 'Prevent Excel from asking: Delete sheet? (when line below is executed.'
sheettodelete.delete
Application.displayalerts = true

End if

.save 'Save MasterWorkbook'

End with

Else

Msgbox("Could not locate master workbook at: " & masterfilepath)

End if

End Sub
```

**To create list:**

Open a new file in Notepad and type the filenames of XLS files; in the specific order and each on its own line. Something like:

```
FIRST.xls
TEST.xls
ASDFSF.xls
MAYA.xls
.... etc.
```

The first filename will be the first worksheet when the code has finished running. Then save the text file as something specific e.g. `ListOfXLSFiles.txt` and in a specific location/folder. Creation of this list only needs to be done once.

**.vbs file**

Try copy-pasting below into Notepad, then saving file as `something.vbs` in a specific location. Then navigate to that location, double-click the file and see how well it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim ExcelAppl, ExcelWorkbook
Set ExcelAppl = createobject("Excel.Application")

' Error trapping is different in VBScript, as I think the error number needs to be examined/cleared via Err methods/members.'

On error resume next
Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelAppl.workbooks.open("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Public\REPORTES\Report\Master.xlsx")

If Not (ExcelWorkbook is nothing) then

' I am unsure if syntax below is correct.'
ExcelAppl.Run "'" & ExcelWorkbook.name & "'!ThisWorkbook.CopySheetsToMasterExcelFile"

ExcelWorkbook.close true 'Save changes to Master file.'
ExcelAppl.Quit

Else
' Could use Msgbox here to alert you if workbook did not open. Not sure if available in VBScript, so have left it out.'
End if

End sub
```

Comment: Okay, maybe describe the errors you're having and post screenshots if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to upload images that day, but internet fail.
[img=https://i.imgur.com/D6TEIIf.png]

Comment: The code I provided was in VBA and can be executed inside a regular Excel workbook. Open a new Excel workbook, press ALT key and F11 together. A window should open. Click on ThisWorkbook in top-left corner of the newly opened window, paste the code there, change XLSFOLDERPATH in the code, then press F5 to execute -- and see how far you get.

Comment: You are AWESOME!!! This works.
How can I give a copy order by workbook? specifically by name
How can I specify a variable value in the name of Master.xlsx file?
Ej. C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\Público\REPORTES\Report 8 January 2018.xlsx
Tomorrow the new value will be: Report 9 January 2018.xls
I have a script that copy a Template.xlsx file on to Report $(date).xlsx file in other path.

Comment: I still don't understand what order you want to copy/insert the sheets in. I have edited the code though to make the master Excel workbook's name variable/dynamic. Have a look, see if it works for you.

Comment: Ej, in the archivos folder. The first one that must be copied is engine machine mount.xls  The second is MAYA PIECES.xls, the third is SUR PIECES.xls and so. I'm going to test your code.

Comment: Compilation error:
A constant expression is necessary

Comment: Can you delete all code you have in the Excel workbook and copy and paste all of the code I have provided? I haven't tested it, but I don't think you should be getting that error.

Comment: Since the order of the workbooks is decided by you (and cannot be determined on the fly/during execution), I think you need to create and store a list of .xls filenames in the order you want to order them in. The list can be any format (.txt, .csv, etc.), but it might be better just to store it in the master Excel workbook on a hidden worksheet for maintenance reasons. Will that work for you? It might cause problems if you are recreating the Master document from a template (unless you change the template to include the hidden sheet containing XLS filenames).

Comment: Error 1004. With the date variable.
How can I set a list.txt or store directly that list in the source code?

Comment: Storing list in source code might make it difficult to maintain, if you need to change it in the future. The easiest way would be in the master Excel file. However, code above uses a regular text file to store list of workbook names.

Comment: This perfectly works.
In my template of masterworkbook has one sheet called hoja1. How can I delete this sheet? and save the changes in the workbook?
You have helped me a lot and I do not know how to thank you

Comment: Thank you so much! There is a possibility to save this in an .exe or a .bat to execute with double click? If you can not, do not worry, you've helped me a lot.

Comment: Have edited code. I'm not as familiar with VBScript, so might not work.